# Check if string contain char and start with it and having numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate string if it contains alphanumeric values and at least 6 character like *abcd*.

I tried with the code below but
I didn't find how to validate if the string start with a **char** and contains at least 6 of it.
The string can have one or several numbers but  cannot start with one.

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_item ) && !regex.IsMatch(_item))
```

Comment: Does the string have to be at least 6 characters total?  Or does it have to have at least 6 alpha characters and can include numbers also?  Provide some examples of strings that are valid and strings that are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `regex`, you can do it with `LINQ`:

```
if( _item.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit) 
    && _item.Count(char.IsLetter) >= 6
    && !char.IsDigit(_item[0])
```

Comment: "the string can have numbers but cannot start with it"

Comment: @Habib now noticed that :) I add extra condition

Comment: They way I understand it that the OP is looking to have a string with atleast 6 characters, your condition would pass for `A12345678`

Comment: @Habib alright then we can change `_item.Lenght > 6` to `_item.Count(char.IsLetter) > 6` :)

Comment: Regex is the better option as it will be most efficient. This will enumerate chars multiple times. Not a problem here as such, but use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$
```

This will match a string that begins with a letter and have at least 6 character.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this

```
  ^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,25}*$
```

Replace 25 with your character maximum length

## [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/XEypMcKUpD)

Comment: This will match a minimum of 7 characters.

Answer (score 1):

> how to validate if the string start with char and contain at least 6
>   of it.

You can do that without REGEX like:

```
string str = "AB123213CDF";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && // for empty string
    char.IsLetter(str[0]) && //Starts with character
    str.Count(char.IsLetter) >= 6)   //Contains atleast 6 letters
{
    //valid
}
else
{
   //invalid
}
```